# .htaccess show subfolder contents on root only but don't show subfolder in address bar

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This is what I currently have in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /subfolder/ [R=301,L]
```

This simply redirects to the subfolder, but I would also like to prevent the subfolder showing in the browser's address bar, and I would only like this to happen on root (main domain page), and all other file requests should go normally, without any redirection at all.

I have tried many solutions here on SO, but all of them either do nothing, simply redirect to the subfolder, or redirect everything, including my style sheets and all removing all the styling and everything from the website.

Is it possible that a rewrite rule would not work on localhost? The redirection does work, but I start to be suspicious apache may not be set up correctly to do other stuff (sorry for my ignorance, I don't know much about apache and redirects).

**EDIT**: a bit more details: this is a PHP (WordPress) install, and this is the root is the only page I would like to redirect, but all other files (ie. CSS styling, JS scripts... etc) that are called to build this page should be called from the root, not from the subfolder. Also all further navigation to other pages on the site should work normally, without any effect of the .htaccess directive I'm setting up.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `subfolder` doesn't have another .htaccess, you can use this code in site root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# externally redirect /subfolder/anything to /anything
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+subfolder/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ subfolder/index.php [NC,L]

# internally forward /anything to /subfolder/anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!subfolder/).+$ subfolder/$0 [NC,L]

# rest of the Wordpress rules go here
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: unfortunately this, while redirecting to the subfolder, is also breaking any styling, because, I believe, it sends the supporting style sheets and js files through the redirect, and so won't find them... sorry, if I wasn't very clear, please have a look at the **EDIT** I just made to the question.

Comment: Do you have wordpress installed in `subfolder/`?

Comment: I'm starting to think I may not have the necessary apache settings turned on correctly... what should they be? any specific requirement?

Comment: So if a request comes as `example.com/something`. Do you want WP to handle `/something` or should it be routed to `/subfolder/something`?

Comment: it should just be `something`, the only redirection should be the "view" of the `subfolder` (index.php) - is this possible at all?

Comment: Try my updated rules on top of your root .htaccess (above other WP rules)

Comment: just tried this, it is now redirecting from `subfolder` to root, but I would like it to happen the other way around, I would like to get redirected *to* `subfolder` from root, but without the url changing... the rest looks really good, so we're getting close!

Comment: If you enter `http://example.com/something`, these rule will internally load `http://example.com/subdfolder/something` but URL will remain `http://example.com/something`

Comment: unfortunately that's not what I'm experiencing... maybe this has to do with the subfolder actually being generated dynamically, not sure... normally, without any redirection, it shows as `example.com/something/` (with a slash at the end), so as if it was the `index.php` file inside the `something` folder, but I'm not entirely sure... the author of the plugin that generates this page says it's not possible to have their plugin at the front page, but I was really hoping I can do it somehow via mod_rewrite, but I'm starting to think this may not be possible...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125952/discussion-between-anubhava-and-webeno).

Answer (score 1):

If some of those redirects you tried actually occurred, then your .htaccess is working.

The `R=301` is what does the redirect, changing the url in the address bar. Remove it and a "rewrite" will be performed, executing the target page without changing the url in the browser.

To rewrite only the base uri '':

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /event/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I hope I followed your instructions correctly, and so the result was the following: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /events/index.php [L]` this simply did nothing at all (went straight to example.com), and did not show the contents of subfolder/index.php

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. I updated the answer, this assumes .htaccess is in the root.

Comment: If this is a wordpress install, where is the wordpress .htaccess?

Comment: .htaccess, as the wordpress install, is in root

Comment: your edited answer doesn't do any redirection either... I'm starting to think I may not have the necessary apache settings turned on correctly... what should they be? any specific requirement?